# How to change object color change using google ARCore SDK at run time in android?

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

I want to implement something like below feature in my AR application for which I use Google ARCore SDK.

Add an object in AR plane. Then select that object and select color from the list of different colors. And change the color of an added object without affecting an added object.

If its possible to change the color of some particular part then it will very fine.

Please help someone to get this concept idea. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sceneform SDK to do that.
This codelab explains in details how to add objects to scene using Sceneform - https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/sceneform-intro/#0
One way of doing what you want to do (maybe not the most efficient) - is to changes appropriate attribute of the renderable, remove the old one from the scene, add updated one into the scene.

Comment: I know how to add an object to a scene. I did not want to do that. Please read my question and description carefully so you can understand what exactly I want. I want to change the color of an object which I added in the scene at runtime without removing it (Color will be selected from color picker dialog).

And in advance I want to change specific part of object color if possible

Comment: In the original question you never mentioned that you don't want the object to be removed. Anyway, yes what you want is achievable. But not in the easy and intuitive way, I would say. Using Sceneform SDK you can get your Node from the scene, from Node you can get Renderable and you can change the Material for Renderable, and Material in it's turn has color property. Another way of doing this would be to use ARCore Unity SDK - here in the MonoBehaviour script you can change the color of the object as easy as this: object.material.color = Color.red;